# MySQL SELECT pattern replace with results from another table

Tags: mysql, replace

How do I substitute values in a SELECT with text matches to rows in another table?

```
**products**
> +-------+--------------------------------------------------+  
> | id    | description                                      |  
> +-------+--------------------------------------------------+  
> | 10001 | This product is %block1% and %block4%            |  
> | 10002 | This product is %block2%, %block3%, and is %block4% |  
> +-------+--------------------------------------------------+  

**descriptions**
> +-----------+-------------------+  
> | blockname | blockcontent      |  
> +-----------+-------------------+  
> | %block1%  | 5 feet tall       |  
> | %block2%  | matte white       |  
> | %block3%  | makes music       |  
> | %block4%  | made of real wood |  
> +-----------+-------------------+
```

Ideally, I'd like to run a single query that returns

```
> +-------+--------------------------------------------------+  
> | id    | newdescription                                      |  
> +-------+--------------------------------------------------+  
> | 10001 | This product is 5 feet tall and made of real wood            |  
> | 10002 | This product is matte white, makes music, and is made of real wood |  
> +-------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I've investigated REPLACE() and SUBSTITUTE() but they don't appear to be what I am looking for.

Comment: This seems like a really odd usage pattern for a relational database.

Comment: Our backend team wants the ability to use various blocks in the product descriptions (many products will share different common blocks).

Comment: I understand the intent, but typically one might use application logic to apply the template substitution, not try to dynamically do it in the database.  I don't see how you are going to get to a query  that does this in an expeditious fashion, so you would likely need to think about caching the substitution results in some manner to allow for a quick lookup.

Comment: Okay, thanks! - I'll just grab the description in PHP in a first query, look to see which blocks are used and then grab those from MySQL in a second query (so that I don't have to grab them all).  Then I'll loop through and substitute in PHP.  I had thought there was likely a quick way to do it in MySQL that I didn't know about (even simpler than the custom function answer), but apparently not and I'll remain happy with the PHP solution.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create function:

```
DROP FUNCTION my_subst;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_subst(str VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pos1 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE pos2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE token VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE new_token VARCHAR(255);

    label1: LOOP
        SET pos1 = LOCATE('%%',str);
        IF pos1 = 0 THEN
            LEAVE label1;
        END IF;

        SET pos2 = LOCATE('%%',str,pos1+1);
        IF pos2 = 0 THEN
            LEAVE label1;
        END IF;

        SET token = SUBSTR(str,pos1,pos2-pos1+2);

        SELECT blockcontent INTO new_token FROM descriptions WHERE blockname = token;

        SET str = REPLACE(str,token,new_token);

    END LOOP label1;
    RETURN str;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and then just use this function to do substitutions.

Comment: Cool, I've never used custom functions before.  Would this be faster than grabbing all of the blocks in a separate query and looping in PHP? (I would assume so)

Comment: It depends on how many calls to this function is expected to be made per each rendered page. If thousands of calls expected, it may worth to preload descriptions table in PHP in some hash, and do substitution in PHP. If only few calls expected, custom SQL function is fine.

Comment: "fast" may not be your primary concern. You could run into scalability problems. By doing the substitution on the database, you aren't taking advantage of relational data structures - every query has to call the my_subst function many times. That means that your database will be working harder. You may find you hit the "my database is slow" bottleneck with fewer concurrent users than if you do the substitution in PHP. And typically, it's easier and cheaper to scale the webservers than the database.